# NDEBUG macro is never defined - MSVC compiler. Is _DEBUG standard?

Tags: c++

As I understand, whenever the compiler is building in release mode, the macro `NDEBUG` is defined, while in debug mode it isn't. That is how `assert` knows when to work.

What I've noticed though is that with the MSVC compiler (2015), `NDEBUG` is never defined, regardless of the build mode.

Anyway, `_DEBUG` is defined. Is this macro standard C++ or some MSVC thing? Should I use it if I'm aiming for compatibility? Does it work with other compilers? (couldn't check) Thanks!

Comment: The only standard usage of a debugging macro is in `assert`, which uses `NDEBUG`.

Comment: Deciding whether to define `NDEBUG` is (intentionally, I believe) left up to you, not done automatically based on debug/release build. Quite a few people prefer to lead `assert`s active in release builds.